# I am absolutely baffled how outside a for-loop a value can be one thing but inside is something else?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, pointers

So I am printing out a pointer array value (the first value since I'm just going through and testing everything) and when I print it outside the for loop literally right before it it displays 3 (which is what I pushed into it) but when I try to print it within the for loop it just prints 0.

I have tested as many processes as I could think of along the way such as when I am incrementing the size by 1 after adding the value I print out the size and it returns the correct changed value, also printing out ptr[0] right after I set it to 3 as well as right before the for loop and both give me 3.

```
void ArrayList::toString()
{
  cout<<"[ ";
  cout<< ptr[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    cout << ptr[0];
  }
}
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
 class ArrayList
    {
    public:
      int *ptr;

    }
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
ArrayList::ArrayList()
{
  this->size = 0;
  this->capacity = 1;
  int array [1];
empty = true;
  array[0] = 0;
ptr = new int[1];
ptr = array;

}

void ArrayList::push(int m)
{
  int* temp;

  if(this->capacity <= this->size)
  {
    temp = new int[capacity * 2];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
      temp[i] = ptr[i];
    }
    capacity *=2;
    delete[] ptr;
    ptr = temp;
  }

  this->ptr[this->size] = m;

  this->size++;
  cout << size;
}
```

Should be getting 3 to my knowledge, I just don't see what can be changing in the literally 2 lines before the print out. If you guys need to see more of my code I can happily provide. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Show how and where you declare `ptr`. I’m guessing it was allocated on the stack.

Comment: ***I just don't see what can be changing in the literally 2 lines*** Could be some type of Undefined Behavior. We probably can't really help without code to reproduce.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  I have added other code including how it is declared (in a header file) and the Default constructor as well as my push method.

Comment: As I suspected. Delete `ptr = array;` Once the constructor exits, `array` no longer exists since it is a local variable.

Comment: I do see what you're saying Johnny but I'm not even referencing i at all in the cout statement so I don't know where that could possibly be coming from but I do agree that seems to be the only place it could really be getting 0.

Comment: And delete everything to do with `array`. Your `ptr` is a dangling pointer. You've got undefined behavior.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that fixed it I'm not sure I exactly understand how, but it did thank you!

Comment: You should really try to understand it as it is an important concept. I’m on my phone and it’s too hard to type but maybe somebody will type a good explanation. If not search for “c++ variable lifetime”

Comment: `cout << ptr[0]` in the loop? Should it be `cout << ptr[i];`?

Answer (score 2):

This section of code here in `ArrayList()` is causing undefined behavior:

```
this->size = 0;
this->capacity = 1;
int array [1];
empty = true;
array[0] = 0;
ptr = new int[1];
ptr = array;
```

When you assign `ptr = array`, you're assigning `ptr` to point to the location where `array` is stored in memory. Because `array` is a local variable, `array` is stored on the stack, so `ptr` is now pointing to a location on the stack.

When you call `ArrayList::toString()`, that happens to overwrite the value pointed to at the location where `array` was stored at. This is what gets printed. In all likelihood, the value at `ptr[0]` gets overwritten during the call to `cout << ptr[0]`, and not by `i` itself.